# Update all styles in doc to left-align

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking for a macro for word documents that will find every style in a document, and change it from whatever it is (centered, justified, right-align) to left-align.

I don't want to change the text (except as a by-product), but the style itself so everything updates.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and then expanding it to loop through all styles?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Remou, I tried working with it, and this seems to work:

```
Sub ChangeStyles()

Dim oSource As Document
Set oSource = ActiveDocument

For i = 1 To oSource.Styles.Count
' must check the style type as character style gives an error
If oSource.Styles(i).Type = wdStyleTypeParagraph Then
With ActiveDocument.Styles(i).ParagraphFormat
.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
End With
Else
End If
Next i

End Sub
```